# What does " 'T' pass" mean in this movie?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What the phrase " 'T' pass" means in this sentence?

> Morgan wanted to get you a 'T' pass.

It's part of the movie "Good will Hunting".
You can watch it [here](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/e88d6844-d978-40a6-9507-854493d12274).

Comment: The question should be "What **does** the phrase 'T pass' **mean** in this sentence?"  Please review how to form questions in English - it is one of the most common things that English learners get wrong.

Comment: yeah it was very embarrassing.

Comment: You might have tried looking it up.

Comment: I tried!
google said :"Teacher-Parent Authorization Security System"
I thought it's a kind of GPS to track a car! but the movie was old and i though it shouldn't be true!

Comment: Well, you missed the main point which is the city of Boston.

Comment: More context might have helped too.  Right before this line, they are talking about how Will is going to get to his job in Cambridge: "Yeah, I figured now that you got your big job over in Cambridge, you needed some way to get over there and I knew I wasn't gonna drive you every day..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A "T Pass" is a transit pass in the city of Boston

https://www.mbta.com/guides/boston-visitor-guide

Comment: "T" being an abbreviation for "Transit".  It should noted that referring to the subway system as "the T" is local Boston slang, and most Americans outside of Boston or New England would be unfamiliar with it.